# Where are the PKI artifacts(pub/priv key and certs) stored for an organization's staff?

Tags: pki

An organization's employee are involved in a network. Each transaction they send will need to be signed against their private keys and will be encoded in the transaction they send.

1) Where are the private/public keys stored? Are they stored locally on an employee's laptop? 
OR 
2) If the organization's employee use different computers to perform daily tasks, would the pub/piv keys be stored on cloud?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice solution to store it on cards as described [here](http://www.finallysoftware.com/home/products/pki/onecard/)

Private key protected by password and stored on card, we can use usb card readers to load key on device and use it to sing requests.

Difference to store certs on devices instead of cloud is that personal devices controlled differently then cloud - you can't protect information if you can't guarantee physical storage protection.

And it is always a question how to maintain CRL.